# TP-LINK TL-WN722N wireless adapter on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb

I bought a TP-LINK WiFi adapter [TL-WN722N] and installed drivers from the CD, but it isn't working. There is no error or something; in Device Manager I have "TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter" in the Network adapters tab but it isn't using it. Is my laptop on-board WiFi [Broadcom] interfering with the TP-LINK USB Adapter? And if so, how can I make so that my laptop uses TP-LINK?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify as how you conclude it's not working?

If you connect a second WIFI-adapter you will need to manually connect it to a WIFI-network. 
It will not copy the configuration (and thus known networks) of your already excising WIFI-adapter.
In the connections tray button ('wifi signal in right bottom corner of screen'), you should be able to connect to a (second) WIFI-network after inserting a password again.

If this is not the case, any of these might help:

1. Find the WIFI-adapter in device manager, see if it functioning properly;
   alternatively, open a command prompt (search for 'cmd') and enter the command 'ipconfig'. Can you see your wireless adapter here?
2. Find new drivers from the website of the supplier;

More information will definetly help.